# How to make a relation between two tables without foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, relationship

I'm a total newbie and I'm trying to do a mysql database, using xampp for linux 1.8.1.

I want to make a relation between two tables A and B. <s>For what I know foreign keys create a bijection, or a one-to-one relation. I must not have such a strict relation, so</s> I only created a column inside table A that stores the id of table B.

Is this correct? There's not a way to enforce it? I mean, **this way you could delete a row of table B that is referenced in table A.** <s>you could store a value inside A that doesn't correspond to an id of any row of B.</s> How to prevent this?

Comment: instead of updating tables directly with SQL statements, write a stored procedure which adds fields *if* it doesn't create orphans by that.
but if you would give details (maybe an sql fiddle too) of what you exactly want to do/store I could give more help

Comment: @Mark: ok, I asked the wrong question. The main problem for me is to prevent deletion of a row of table B if the row id is referenced by a row of table A. I'll update the question.

Comment: followup: I didn't added an example because I don't understand the correct way to do this thing in general.

Comment: quoted "For what I know foreign keys create a bijection, or a one-to-one relation." this is false, foreign keys are used in 1:1, 1:N and N:N relations

Comment: @Tiago Almeida: thank you, corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The main problem for me is to prevent deletion of a row of table B if the row id is referenced by a row of table A.

```
create table table_b (
  b_id integer primary key
);

create table table_a (
  b_id integer primary key references table_b (b_id)
);

insert into table_b values (1);
insert into table_a values (1);
```

The following statement will fail.

```
delete from table_b where b_id = 1;
```

If you'd built that with PostgreSQL, the error message would say

> ERROR: update or delete on table "table_b" violates foreign key constraint "table_a_b_id_fkey" on table "table_a" Detail: Key (b_id)=(1) is still referenced from table "table_a".

That structure gives you a "1 to 0 or 1" relationship between the two tables. For "1 to 0 or many", add one or more columns to table_a's primary key.

```
create table table_b (
  b_id integer primary key
);

create table table_a (
  b_id integer references table_b (b_id),
  checkout_date date not null default current_date,
  primary key (b_id, checkout_date)
);
```

That structure will let table_a store multiple rows for one value of b_id, but each of those rows must have a different checkout_date.

Comment: It works. It seems I've not understood well foreign keys, since I thought they create a bijection. Many thanks! PS: mysql is non-standard, so requires a foreign key clause apart. Inline "references" are ignored.

Answer (score 1):

I think you allways need an primarykey for [this](http://oak.cs.ucla.edu/cs143/project/mysql/constraints.html), or you write a trigger who checks the consistence of ID from B when a change occurs.
I dont know that it would be possible without a trigger or a constraint ...

Comment: I updated the question, see it and/or my first comment to the question.

Comment: So just that i get it right. You mean you want to prevent the delete of the "associated" row in Table B if you delete a row in Table A ?

Comment: Exactly, and the reversal too.

Comment: Yes! PS: I wronged before, the reversal is not needed nor appreciated... what a mess I've done with this question :(